# how to avoid using context.getbean in spring

Tags: spring

There have been several arguments around not using ApplicationContext.getBean() to get a bean reference, of which most are based on logic that it violates the principles of Inversion of control.

Is there a way to get reference to prototype scoped bean without calling context.getBean() ?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)!

Than you can do something like this...

**Runner:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Some Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    // Spring Boot injecting beans through @Autowired annotation
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CoolFeature") // Use Qualifier annotation to mark a class, if for example
                                    //  you have more than one concreate class with differant implementations of some interface.
    private CoolFeature myFeature;

    public void testFeature(){
            myFeature.doStuff();
    }
}
```

**Some cool feature:**

```
@Component("CoolFeature") // To identify with Qualifier
public class CoolFeature{

    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherBean utilityBean;

    public void doStuff(){
        // use utilityBean in some way 
    }
}
```

No XML files to handle.
We can still access context for manual configurations if needed.

**Suggested reading:**

[Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/)

[Pro Spring Boot](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIT705IT705&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Pro%20spring%20boot%20&*)

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem can be solved using method injection, which is described in more detail here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common approach to create prototype bean:

```
abstract class MyService {
     void doSome() {
         OtherService otherService = getOtherService();
     }
     abstract OtherService getOtherService();
}

@Configuration
class Config {    
    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
         return new MyService() {
             OtherService getOtherService() {
                 return otherService();
             }
         }
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public OtherService otherService() {
        return new OtherService();
    } 
}
```